# Allow anonymous access to a single WCF service method

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service with message security and Username credentials. Most of my methods are starting with

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = ConstStrings.Roles.Admin)]
```

and these methods are supposed to be called only by authenticated users.

I want to add a method which would be called by an anonymous, but I receive an error:

> The username is not provided. Specify username in ClientCredentials.

I am loking for something similar to MVC's `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute

Comment: Then allow anonymous ClientCredentials for the connection?

Comment: @Herdo, that's what i'm looking for. But how?

Comment: So when allowing anonymous access, there shouldn't be any `PrincipalPermission`-attribute, right? So what is throwing the exception then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option would be to implement your own `ServiceAuthorizationManager` and use your own custom attribute rather than `PrincipalPermission`

Basically, you will have to inherit from `ServiceAuthorizationManager`. Plug this into your WCF pipeline by adding the following configuration into your web.config (assuming your class is called 'CustomAuthorizationManager' in the Org.Namespace namespace.

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <!--<serviceAuthorization impersonateCallerForAllOperations="true" />-->
      <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="Org.Namespace.CustomAuthorizationManager, Org.Namespace" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

In your custom Authorization class, you will have to override the `CheckAccessCore` method as shown below. In there you can check for the custom attribute you've created (this will just be an ordinary .Net attribute that you will create with whatever properties you want).

```
    protected override bool CheckAccessCore(OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        string action = operationContext.IncomingMessageHeaders.Action;
        DispatchOperation operation = operationContext.EndpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.Operations.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Action == action);
        Type hostType = operationContext.Host.Description.ServiceType;
        MethodInfo method = hostType.GetMethod(operation.Name);
        var myCustomAttributeOnMethod = method.GetCustomAttributes(true).Where(a => a.GetType() == typeof (MyCustomAttribute)).Cast<MyCustomAttribute>();
    .
    .
    .
    }
```

Now you can inspect the custom attribute and perform any functions as you see fit. For example, if the custom attribute's "AllowAnonymous" flag is set, you might skip the role check. Otherwise, you might get the user's windows identity and check they are in the particular role.

And of course you need to decorate the relevant methods with your custom attribute rather than PrincipalPermission.

To summarize, basically what you are doing is decorating all your methods with your own ordinary custom .Net attribute that provides some information. i.e this method allows anonymous, this method requires this role etc. etc. You then update your web.config file to tell WCF to use your own service authorization manager. You implement your own service authorization manager where you get access to the method that is being called, inspect it's custom attribute and say "Yay" or "Nay" accordingly.

Comment: Is there a way to do this, but still use PrincipalPermission?

Answer (score 1):

You could do as you suggested above, and then use this snippet to check which specific method was called:

```
var requestedOperation = 
    OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.Action.Split('/').Last();
```

This would result in the following:

```
public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
{
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
    {
        var requestedOperation = 
            OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.Action.Split('/').Last();

        if("myAnonymousOperation" == requestedOperation)
        {        
            // Allow anonymous access here.
            return;
        }
    }

    // Allow/deny users that provide credentials
    ValidateOtherCredentials(userName, password);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom `UserNamePasswordValidator` like shown in [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/96028/WCF-Service-with-custom-username-password-authenti) tutorial. This validator need to implement the `Validate` method, in order to allow anonymous access.

```
public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
{
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
    {
        // Allow anonymous access here.
        return;
    }

    // Allow/deny users that provide credentials
    ValidateOtherCredentials(userName, password);
}
```

**Note:** If you allow anonymous access, the authorization process using the `PrincipalPermission` still requires credentials. I'm not sure, but this might cause an exception at runtime.

Comment: @Anarion Did you give it a try?

Comment: this is a good solution, and I didn't come up with anything better yet, but I want to allow anonymous access only to a single method, so I want something simular to MVC `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute

Comment: this solution doesnt work, because you cant get information about the method that is called from within the Validate method.