# How to get the service's method name in custom UserNamePasswordValidator

Tags: c#, wcf

I use `UserNamePasswordValidator` in my WCF-service. As I know, there is imposible to off this validation for some specific method inside service. That's why I'm trying to get the method's name in `Validate` method for skiping validation if client call this concrete method. But I don't know where I can find it.

P.S. `OperationContext.Current` object is nulleable inside `Validate` method

**Edited**:
Here is my service:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public HttpStatusCode InserOrUpdate(string param1, long param2, int param3)
    {
        ...
    }

    public string GetPublicKey()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And here is my custom validator:

```
public class CustomUserNamePasswordValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        if(/* currentServiceMethodName == "GetPublicKey" */)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Next code decrypts userName/password and checks permissions in DB. 

    }
}
```

Web.config:

```
...
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      ...
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="MyNamespace.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator, MyNamespace" />
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
...
```

Comment: Please include your code.

Comment: Ok. the code is here from now

Comment: Have a look at this question, maybe that's what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25293641/254797